# AWS Batch job getting Access Denied on S3 despite user role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-batch

I am deploying my first batch job on AWS. When I run my docker image in an EC2 instance, the script called by the job runs fine.  I have assigned an IAM role to this instance to allow S3 access.

But when I run the same script as a job on AWS Batch, it fails due to Access Denied errors on S3 access.  This is despite the fact that in the Job Definition, I assign an IAM role (created for Elastic Container Service Task) that has full S3 access.

If I launch my batch job with a command that does not access S3, it runs fine.

Since using an IAM role for the job definition seems not to be sufficient, how then do I grant S3 permissions within a Batch Job on AWS?

**EDIT**

So if I just run  `aws s3 ls interlinked` as my job, that also runs properly.  What does not work is running the R script:

```
 library(aws.s3)
 get_bucket("mybucket")[[1]]
```

Which fails with Access Denied.

So it seems the issue is either with the `aws.s3` package or, more likely, my use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I had IAM Roles specified for both my compute environment (more restrictive) and my jobs (less restrictive).

In this scenario (where role based credentials are desired), the `aws.s3` R package uses `aws.signature` and `aws.ec2metadata` to pull temporary credentials from the role.  It pulls the compute environment role (which is an ec2 role), but not the job role.

My solution was just to grant the required S3 permissions to my compute environment's role.

Comment: so you were using two separate roles one with more permissions and the other with lesser perms?  I already have a role that is associated with the ec2 instance but I still am running into the issue

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K yes I had two roles. In my case, I had to ensure the role associated with the compute environment had sufficient permissions.