# (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden when accessing S3 from AWS Batch in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-batch

I have created a docker image that was generated from amazonlinux.  It in I manually installed python3, pip and awscli.  I also configured the AWSCLI to use my key and secret key.  When I create a container from the image, I can interact with S3 without problems.

I then generate a new image from my custom image above using a Dockerfile.  In it, I install the modules needed for this task (boto3, numpy, pandas, scipy and spacy) and also the custom python code.  This image is the container I use for AWS Batch.

My custom python code tries to download a file from S3 using:

```
jsonText = None
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
with io.BytesIO() as file_stream:
    s3.download_fileobj(args.input_transcript_s3_bucket, args.input_transcript_s3_key, file_stream)
    wrapper = io.TextIOWrapper(file_stream, encoding='utf-8')
    wrapper.seek(0)
    jsonText = wrapper.read()
    wrapper.flush()
    file_stream.flush()
```

When the python code gets triggered through AWS Batch, I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

[Another post on stackoverflow suggests adding the region to the S3 client create call.  As in the other poster's case, this didn't help me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795236/downloading-files-from-aws-s3-bucket-with-boto3-results-in-clienterror-an-error)

I am thinking this is a policy issue.  I have checked out the VPC Endpoint Policy and found it to be sufficient:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have generated a custom batch service role.  To it I added the AWSBatchServiceRole and also the AmazonS3FullAccess policies.  I assigned this new service role to a brand new compute environment with no luck.

I am not sure what to do next or how to get more information.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is ~solved, but here's a debug idea. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094271/aws-batch-job-getting-access-denied-on-s3-despite-user-role) and [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-compute-environment.html). Are your service role *and* instance role both set up with the needed permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker container was being started with 'nobody' as the user.  The AWS configuration (specifically the .aws directory) was only accessible as the root user.

I changed the docker container to copy the .aws directory from /root to the root of the HD and then made it accessible to 'nobody':

```
cp -r /root/.aws /
chown nobody /.aws
chgrp nobody /.aws
cd /.aws
chown nobody *
chgrp nobody *
```

I then tested to make sure 'nobody' could access the credentials:

```
su -s /bin/bash nobody
aws s3 ls
```

This solved my problem.

[I am not very happy with this solution since it exposes my AWS key and secret key to the 'nobody' user, but find myself in a bit of a catch 22.  I created this post to see if there are other options.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548149/catch-22-with-user-nobody-and-aws-configure-on-amazonlinux-docker-image)